# php gives error and wont move file

Tags: php, file-upload

i have a upload page set up at this time that allows a user to upload one image at a time and im trying to change to allow multiple pics to be upload with a tag. when i went in and made changes to the form it tells me that there is an error with line 19 and 43 not be parameters. (error #1) strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\webstuffs\upload.php on line 19. (error #2)move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\wamp\www\webstuffs\upload.php on line 43.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file']))
{

$file = $_FILES ['file'];
$name = $file ['name'];
$type = $file ['type'];
$size = $file ['size'];
$tmppath = $file ['tmp_name']; 


                        function create_slug($slug, $hyphenate = true)
                            {
                            19. $slug = strtolower($slug);
                                if($hyphenate)
                                    {
                                $slug = preg_replace("/[-\s\W]/","-",$slug);
                                    }
                                 return preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9-]/", "",strtolower($slug));
                            }
                        $name=create_slug($name);






    $res=$ob->upload();
    $user=$_SESSION['user'];
    $tmp=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        $tag=$row['sno'];

        if(isset($_POST[$tag]))
            {
            43. move_uploaded_file ($tmppath, 'images/gallery/'.$name.'.jpg');
                mysql_query("insert into gallery(image,tag,user) values('".$name."','".$tag."','".$user."')");
                $tmp=1;
            }
    }   










}
?>
```

and this is the form

```
<form name="f3" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data";>
            <div style="clear:both;margin-left:50px;height:40px; ">
                <div style="float:left;width:150px;font-size:25px;font-family:'Monotype Corsiva'; color:#fc6464;font-weight:bold;margin-top:-8px;">Choose Image</div>
                <div style="float:left;width:40px;color:#CCCCCC; ">:</div>
                <div style="float:left;width:200px; "><input type="file" name="file[]" multiple id="file" style="width:180px; "></div>
            </div>




                <div class="multiselect">

                <?php

                $res=$ob->alltags();
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
                        {
                            $tags=$row['tags'];
                            $sno=$row['sno'];
                            echo"<label><input type='checkbox' name='".$sno."' value='".$sno."' />$tags</label>";
                        }
                    ?>

        </div>

        <br/>

        <div style="clear:both;margin-left:50px;height:40px; ">
                <div style="width:120px;font-size:25px;font-family:'Monotype Corsiva'; color:#fc6464;font-weight:bold;margin-top:-8px;">Select Tags</div>

                <div style="clear:both;margin-left:0px;height:40px; ">
                <a href="javascript:void();" onClick="blank3();"><img src="images/submit.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void();" onClick="blank1();"><img src="images/reset.png"></a>
            </div>

            </div>

            </form>
```

i looked everything over and I have no idea what i need to do to fix this

Comment: You are getting data in array form, so you have to iterate over that data to process every “record” individually. If you are not clear about the structure of the data you are receiving, then make a debug output using var_dump at the beginning of your script.

Comment: its written even in the error messages. your data types dont fit the requirements. your $slug is an array but should be a string. do a var_dump($slug) and check whats inside and why its like this. with the other error you can do same.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$slug` is an array after using `preg_replace`.
2. `$_FILES['file']` is also an array, because you used in your input name `files[]`.

So, you have to loop through both arrays and then they will be used as string in function's variables.

so `$tmppath = $file['tmp_name'];` should be in a loop and like: `$tmppath = $file[$i]['tmp_name'];`